# Wrong way of teaching

Tags: mathematics, teaching, asia

I am from a South Asian country. I did my Msc in mathematics from a flagship university in our country. I think some parts of the course structure and the syllabus is incorrect. For example Differential Manifold is taught in 1st semester but several variable calculus ( Inverse Function theorem, Implicit Function Theorem etc) which is a prerequisite for the course, is taught in 2nd semester. I think it is clearly 'Rote Learning'. What steps can be taken against it ?

Comment: Steps from whom? From you? Do you have  a lot of power in your political/university system?

Comment: How is "Rote Learning" viewed in your country? How "open" to suggestions is your university? Do they care about quality of teaching?

Comment: In our country, 'Rote Learning' is considered a bad practice ( theoretically). But in practical, lion's share of the academic follow it. Students are taught to memorize stuff in any subject since childhood.

Comment: @Noname: then you probably can't do anything (unless you are a professor or politician).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you will have much effect except at a personal level unless you join academia and influence curriculum over time.

There may be reasons for the current structure that you aren't aware of. Conversations with (trusted) faculty members about the philosophy of the program and the reasons for certain structures can both help you understand why this is and, perhaps, suggest other, better, ways of doing things.

But an outsider, even a graduate, will probably have little impact.

If both semesters are taught by the same person it is possible that a teaching technique called Spiral Education might be at play here. The first semester introduces things at a less-than-complete level that is only finished in the second semester. Of course this assumes a well thought out plan for getting students to the right spot by the end. It is even possible that the first semester is intended to teach "just enough" to get people going in a subject so that if they don't take the second semester they can still use what they learned. That may be more applicable to other things that mathematics, I suppose, but I can't see into the minds of the curriculum designer.

But a conversation with people involved might be valuable, both to yourself and to the institution.